# How to style google SwitchMaterial button on Android?

Tags: android, layout, material-design, material-components-android

I have a material switch button like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                android:id="@+id/effectEnabled"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle2"
                android:checked="true"
                android:enabled="true" />
```

here's the style:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle2" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <!--<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>-->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```

with these styles, the button gets broken and with a square background of grey color.

How can I style SwitchMaterial buttons? I just want to change the switch color

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `app:thumbTint` and/or `app:trackTint` to change the switch colors.
For better results define a `ColorStateList` in `res/color` (ie: `res/color/custom_thumb_selector.xml`) to have differente colors based on if it is checked or not.
ie:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/customChecked" />
    <item android:color="@color/customUnchecked" />
</selector>
```

and then set it in your style:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle2" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="thumbTint">@color/custom_thumb_selector</item>
</style>
```

*Note: Your custom style should inherit from `Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch`*

Comment: Can you update to specify where do I save the selector file and how I set it into the switch?